# Which of the following statement is true and how?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, graphing-functions

An engineer measures THREE quantities $X, Y$ and $Z$ in an experiment. She finds that they follow a relationship that is represented in the figure below:
[image: Graph of Z versus (X.Y)]

(the product of $X$ and $Y$ linearly varies with $Z$).
Then, which of the following statements is FALSE?

1. For fixed $Y$; $X$ is proportional to $Z$
2. For fixed $Z$; $X$ is proportional to $Y$
3. $XY/ Z$ is constant
4. For fixed $X$ ; $Z$ is proportional to $Y$.

**My attempt:** We see that $XY=\lambda Z\implies XY/Z=\lambda=\text{constant}$. Is it correct?

Comment: The body of your question is different from (though equivalent to) the title.  You say that you have made an attempt, and ask whether it is correct, but you haven't answered the question you posed, so how do we know whether it is correct?  (Also, I find that picture hard to read.  Is the vertical axis labelled "$(X.Y)$" (the product) or "$(X, Y)$" (an ordered pair, in which case I don't know how to interpret the picture)?)

Comment: As the comment of @LSpice indicates, your *work* has merely demonstrated that you have determined that statement 3 is true.  You have shown **no work** in trying to determine which of statements 1,2, or 4 are true.

Comment: Your attempt looks good to me. So which of the 4 options is false, given your observation?

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 is wrong. If we fix $Z$ we have

$$ XY = C $$

So $X$ isn't *directly* proportional to $Y$, as in $ X = YC $.

Also: your attempt is correct.